# CodeIgniter won't redirect to controllers, Apache gives 404, base contoller works

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, redirect, xampp

So, I wanted to learn MVC with PHP and made a simple project.

I have configured XAMPP and an alias /gambit that redirects to my project directory, don't know if it's important or not.

This is my controller users.php:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Users extends CI_Controller 
{
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->model('user');
    $this->load->helper('url');

}

public function account()
{
    $data = array();
    if($this->session->userdata('isUserLoggedIn'))
    {
        $data['user'] = $this->user->getRows(array('id'=>$this->session->userdata('userId')));
        $this->load->view('account',$data);
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('login');
    }
}

public function login()
{
    $data=array();
    if($this->session->userdata('success_msg'))
    {
        $data['success_msg'] = $this->session->userdata('success_msg');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('successs_msg');

    }
    if($this->session->userdata('error_msg'))
    {
        $data['error_msg'] = $this->session->userdata('error_msg');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('error_msg');
    }
    if($this->input->post('loginSubmit'))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == true)
        {
            $con['returnType'] = 'single';
            $con['conditions'] = array(
                'email' =>$this->input->post('email'),
                'password' => md5($this->input->post('password')),
                'status' => '1'
            );

            $checkLogin = $this->user->getRows($con);
            if($checkLogin)
            {
                $this->session->set_userdata('isUserLoggedIn',TRUE);
                $this->session->set_userdata('userId',$checkLogin['id']);
                redirect('account');
            }
            else
            {
                $data['error_msg'] = 'Wrong E-mail or password, please try again.';
            }
        }
    }
    $this->load->view('login', $data);
}

public function registration()
{
    $data = array();
    $userData = array();
    if($this->input->post('regisSubmit'))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required|valid_email|callback_email_check');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','password','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('conf_password','confirm password','required|matches[password]');

        $userData = array(
            'email' =>strip_tags($this->input->post('email')),
            'password' => md5($this->input->post('password'))
        );

        if($this->form_validation->run() == true)
        {
            $insert = $this->user->insert($userData);
            if($insert)
            {
                $this->session->set_userdata('success_msg','Registration successful! Please, log in');
                redirect ('login');
            }
            else
            {
                $data['error_msg'] = 'An error occured. Please, try again later.';
            }
        }
    }

    $data['user'] = $userData;
    $this->load->view('registration',$data);
}

public function logout()
{
    $this->session->unset_userdata('isUserLoggedIn');
    $this->session->unset_userdata('userId');
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    $this->load->view('login',$data);
}

public function email_check($str)
{
    $con['returnType'] = 'count';
    $con['conditions'] = array('email'=>$str);
    $checkEmail = $this->user->getRows($con);
    if($checkEmail>0)
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('email_check','The given email already exists.');
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

}

Function registration() is problematic, I want it to redirect to login() function of a controller after successful registration, instead Apache gives me error 404 object could not be found.

I tried 'login', '/login' 'users/login' and so on to no avail

If I set login as a base controller, it works like a charm.

I have rewrite_mod enabled in my xampp and this is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

Config.php:

```
$config['index_page'] =  ''; 
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"; //tried AUTO too
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/gambit/';
```

Project structure:

[image: struct]

Comment: Tip: name your users model to User_model.php same for class as if have same class as controller can cause some errors now and again,

Comment: Also name your controller file Users.php where the first letter is uppercase   only https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Answer (score 0):

```
 redirect('index.php/Users/login');
```

you must see the sensitive case.

your controller filename "users" but your class is "Users".

change your controller filename to be Users.

hope this answer can solved your problem.

Comment: Problem still persists

Comment: are you not using the .htaccess?

Comment: if you not using the .htaccess, you can use
   redirect('index.php/Users/login')

Answer (score 0):

`.htaccess` must be like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```